# Custom node position in dagree-d3

Tags: dagre-d3, dagre

I have a directed acylic graph done with [dagre-d3](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre-d3). Is there any possibility to put a node in a different level and change the position of a node with some code? This library has some 'rank constraints' but it looks like in the latest version it's not working. My current suggestion is adding some links and hide them after that, but it's the last possible option and I really want to avoid it.

Currently, my graph looks as follow and my goal is put one cluster under other [image: graph]

Comment: Every figure out a way to force/pin a node to a given position?